# Is there a way to make a tooltip text show in random location in the button area when clicked?

Tags: java, swing

In case you didn't know, I'm currenty working on a cookie clicker remake for pc and I would like to add a new feature to it.
I want to show a tooltip text in random location around the button area(copy and try the code..).

So I want to randomly generate the tooltip location and of course make it show after the button is clicked.

I have this simple code as an example:

```
package com.tominocz.cookieclicker;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Gui {

    static JFrame f = new JFrame("test gui");
    static JButton b1 = new JButton("click me");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(b1);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object source = e.getSource();
                if (source instanceof JButton) {
                    // make the tooltip show around the button area after clicking
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now how can I make it do what I want?

Comment: yeah and just because on stack overflow you get the answer many times faster

Comment: @camickr Can you aswer then please?
I really need that code..

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `JToolTip` class and setBounds of the tool tip. I did not try this approach but [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html) may help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JButton#getToolTipLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipLocation(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) to return a `Point` within the component's coordinate context for where you want the tool tip displayed.  The default implementation return's `null`, which allows the Swing API to make decisions about where the tooltip should be displayed.